# How do I sync with the server so that the relay store is up to date?

Tags: graphql, relayjs

Let's say I am using a third party API service for uploading images.

After uploading an image, I should update the currently visible relay state for the new image url.

What's the best way to sync with the server after data mutations that are not done via Relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the data is in the datastore that relay uses on the backend, you can use forceFetch to refetch all fragments in your container.

https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-container.html#forcefetch